# In LitElement, how do I refresh external data in a child-component?

Tags: lit-element, lit

I have a child-component which takes a property (`group`). The child-component uses this property as an argument in a URL for fetching external data which it then renders as a list. The problem is, the child-component completes the render before fetch returns, using stale data from the previous fetch.

`foods.js` the parent component,

```js
import {LitElement, html} from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/lit/dist@2/all/lit-all.min.js";

import "./summary.js"

export class MyFoods extends LitElement {
    _dropdown(event) {
        if (event === undefined) {
            return
        }

        this.food = event.target.value
        console.log("_dropdown: " + this.food)
        this.requestUpdate()
    }

    constructor() {
        super()
        this.food = "all"
    }

    render() {
        return html`
        <select @click="${this._dropdown}">
            <option value="all">all</option>
            <option value="fruit">fruit</option>
            <option value="veg">veg</option>
        </select>
        <my-summary .group=${this.food}></my-summary>
        `
    }
}

customElements.define("my-foods", MyFoods)
```

`summary.js` the child component,

```js
import {LitElement, html} from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/lit/dist@2/all/lit-all.min.js";


export class MySummary extends LitElement {
    static properties = {
        group: {
            type: String
        }
    }

    _loadSummary() {
        let url = "/" + this.group
        console.log("url: " + url)

        let that = this

        fetch(url, {
            "credentials": "same-origin"
        })
        .then((resp) => resp.json())
        .then(function(data) {
            console.log(data)
            that._rows = []

            data.forEach(r => that._rows.push({"value": r.value}))
            // that.requestUpdate()
        })
    }

    constructor() {
        super()
        this.group = "all"
        this._rows = []

        console.log(this.group)
        // this._loadSummary()
    }

    render() {
        console.log("render: " + this.group)
        this._loadSummary()
        return html`
        <p>${this.group}</p>
        <ul>
            ${[...this._rows].map(r => html`<li>${r.value}</li>`)}
        </ul>
        `
    }
}

customElements.define("my-summary", MySummary)
```

Comment: `this.food` needs to be a property for it to be reactive. See https://lit.dev/docs/components/properties/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would remove `this._loadSummary()` from `render()`, otherwise you'll easily create an endless loop where you trigger an update, which triggers `this._loadSummary`, which triggers an update etc...

`this.food` and `this._rows` must be reactive properties:

```js
static properties = {
  group: {
    type: String,
    state: true
  },
  _rows: {
    state: true
  }
}
```

Then run your function whenever `group` changes:

```js
updated(changedProperties) {
    changedProperties.forEach((oldValue, newValue) => {
        if (newValue === "group") {
          this._loadSummary()
        });
    }
```

Then you can remove `this._loadSummary` from render and constructor, because it runs automatically whenever `this.group` is updated, and your component renders whenever `this._rows` changes.

You can also bind `this._loadSummary` in your constructor to avoid having to write `let that = this`:

```js
constructor() {
  super()
  this.group = "all"
  this._rows = []

  this._loadSummary = this._loadSummary.bind(this);
}
```